# How to respond to mouse button clicks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to write code to respond (seperately) to the following events:

1. Right hand click
2. Left hand click
3. Middle button click (optional - nice to have but I can live without this).

Is there an inbuilt way in Javascript that I can respond to these events, or do I need to use a library (preferably jQuery) ?

Answer (score 3):

Quirks mode has [a decent guide](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button), it is more complicated then it needs to be due to browser differences.

> do I need to use a library (preferably jQuery) ?

JavaScript libraries can't do anything that you can't do yourself; they just make it easier to do some things.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your_element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which)
    {
        case 1:
            // left mouse
            break;
        case 2:
            // middle mouse
            break;
        case 3:
            // right mouse
            break;
        default:
            // some sort of bizarre mouse! fallback
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hehe ... this is why I LOVE jQuery!

Comment: @skyeagle - jQuery is a typical love it or hate it kind of scenario. I love it because of the fantastic selectors and because I never need to worry about cross-browser differences like there are in this very example if you were to code this with 'normal' JavaScript.

Comment: Important to note that nothing you do in the `mousedown` event will prevent the context menu on most browsers (e.g., right-click). You have to explicitly hook the `contextmenu` event, if supplied. See the guide that [David talks about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850498/how-to-respond-to-mouse-button-clicks-in-javascript/3850519#3850519) for more information. Example: http://jsbin.com/anofi3

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function I use:

```
var ieButtons = { "1": "left", "2": "right", "3": "leftright", "4": "middle" };

function getMouseButton(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.which == "number") {
        // Non-IE case. Works in everything apart from Opera < 8
        return (evt.which < 2) ? "left" :
            ( (evt.which == 2) ? "middle" : "right" );
    } else {
        // IE case
        return ieButtons[evt.button] || "unknown";
    }
}

document.onmousedown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    window.alert( getMouseButton(evt) );
};
```

Jan Wolter's article on mouse events is seemingly less well-known than his one on key events but is just as good, and knocks quirksmode into a cocked hat: http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html

Having just looked at the jQuery code, it looks as though it normalizes the `which` property of the event correctly (1 for left, 2 for middle, 3 for right), although without IE's nice feature of reporting multiple simultaneous button presses.

Answer (score -1):

from MSDN: [onclick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536913%28VS.85%29.aspx)
from MSDN: [button property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That's Microsoft specific. All three earlier answers have already pointed to cross browser solutions.

Comment: you are right, that's from microsoft website, i mentioned it with "from MSDN" phrase. i thought maybe it could help him(even a little).